# Servlet does not persist an Entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

**What do I want to do:**

I just started with JPA and therefore i want to understand how persisting Entitys from different perspectives work (Application-Managed, Container-Managed). Application-Managed works fine, however i have problems persisting an Entity with an Entity Manager from within a Web Application using a TestServlet.

**What have I done so far:**

IDE: NetBeans 8.0.2
Server: GlassFish 4.1
Mysql 5.6
JPA 2.1: EclipseLink

1. I've created a Web Application Project.
2. I've imported the Entitys from the Database using the NetBeans Wizard.
   For some reason I am not able to import them from jdbc/__default.
   I have to create a new Data Source. In this case it was jdbc/__onlineshop

I simply want to create an Entity within a Servlet and persist it in the database just to understand how it works before I move on but apparently I don't quite get it.

I am connected to the database and i can access it via a Java-Application but not using a Servlet from a Web-Container.

The MySQL Driver is in the classpath MAIN - Libraries.

No Exceptions are thrown. The Servlet is called which I am able to see in the browser. However the redirection through the RequestDispatcher does not work either, the browsers URL stays at web-jpa/test.

**My Question:**

Is there anything wrong with my Servlet or the persistence.xml since persisting does not work ?

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/ persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="jpa-webPU" transaction-type="JTA">
 <jta-data-source>jdbc/__onlineshop</jta-data-source>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```

TestServlet.java :

```
package jpa;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Resource
private UserTransaction ut;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setEmail("email@test.com");
    customer.setPassword("password");

    try 
    {
        ut.begin();
        em.persist(customer);
        ut.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        try 
        {
            ut.rollback();

        } catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());

    }finally
    {
        em.close();
    }

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher    ("index.html");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
}
```

Thank you !

p.s.: Any Hint is appreciated !

Comment: You're confusing redirect and forward. A forward simply transfers the responsibility of handling a request to another component. It can't change the URL. A redirect (using HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()) sends a response to the browser and tells it to go to another URL. That can change the URL.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: I've edited the post. The basic question would be: Is there anything wrong with how i approached persisting an Entity within a servlet ? I don't get why it does not persist the Entity in the database.

Comment: If it doesn't throw any exception, then your entity has probably been persisted. Make sure to look at the right database. That said, you should not use the EM from a servlet. Delegate to a transactional CDI bean or stateless EJB. Use declarative transaction management instead of those horrible try/catch/commit/rollback blocks.

Comment: Ok thx. My intention was just to try it to see whether i got it or not but i guess i'll proceed to EJB since this does not seem to be a correct way of using this. The entity has not been persisted since i have only one database.

Comment: Please, move to EJB. This way you don't need to manually obtain the entity manager from nor to manually mess around with ugly user transactions and manual rollbacks. All you need is then an `em.persist(entity);` line inside an EJB method. Just create a class, annotate it `@Stateless`, add a `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;` field and add public methods working on it. Finally inject it in servlet via `@Inject` and let it in turn invoke one such EJB method. That's all. A single stateless EJB method call counts transparently as a single full transaction, with rollback and all on it.

Comment: Yes I will move to EJB, i just wanted to apply it in order to see if i've understood it. Personally i don't see the point in moving directly to higher level applications without understanding the need for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution:

```
try
{
  ut.begin();
  em.joinTransaction(); // this is necessary, the entitymanager needs to be called specifically
  em.persist(customer);
  ut.commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the files in the shown structure. The Entity can be persisted. It worked for me [image]